# Change order that the menu is generated with wp_list_pages

Tags: php, menus, wp-list-pages

I am trying to order the output of one of my menus to be based off of the way they are setup in the `Appearance->Menus` pane, however it seems to only want to do it alphabetically.

For example I have setup in the `Menus` pane the following hierarchy:

```
Weekly Outlook
- Webinars
- Calendar
```

However it displays like so:

```
Weekly Outlook
- Calendar
- Webinars
```

I the menu is generated by the following code. Note, the content is dependant on the page visited.

```
 <div id="dep-menu">
 <?php global $post;
 if (!is_front_page() && !is_404()) {
     if($post->post_parent) {
         $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order'");
         $children.= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order'");
     } else {
         $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->ID."&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order'");
         $children.= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order'");
     }
     if ($children) { ?>
         <ul>
             <?php echo $children; ?>
         </ul>
     <?php }
 }
 ?>
 </div>
```

**EDIT**

Here it is in action: http://dailywealthreport.com.au/

The menu I am referring to is the one that comes up when you click on an item in the main menu.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `wp_nav_menu` function?

Comment: possibly, I don't want it to be a "page menu" it's essentially a glorified breadcrumbs only it point's "forward"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ['menu_order'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_Pages_by_Page_Order) to work, you need to set the page order from the page edit screen. Are you setting orders for your pages?

Comment: I edited the post to link to the page in question. The "main menu" is done with `wp_nav_menu` and it includes the child pages. I want to `echo` those child pages in accordance with the order set out in the menu order.

Comment: I got your point, but as you're using `wp_list_pages`, there doesn't seem to be a straight way to do it. I guess using `wp_nav_menu` itself by excluding the parent will do your job.